# preceding and NOT current row

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, range, date-arithmetic

I'm trying to get get the last year average on a result set in postgres using this:

```
SELECT
    *,
   avg(units) OVER (                                              -- 3
       ORDER BY to_date(isoyear::text || '-' || week::text, 'IYYY-IW')      -- 1
       RANGE between interval '1 year' preceding and 1 preceding )
FROM
    mytable
   order by isoyear,week;
```

But I'm getting this error:

> SQL Error [22000]: ERROR: can't coerce leading frame bound to type of
> trailing frame bound   Hint: specify the leading and trailing frame
> bounds as the same type

I tried just preceding but I get syntax error:

```
RANGE between interval '1 year' preceding)
```

What am I missing? I don't want the preceding and current row, I just need the preceding rows 1 year back..

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need both bounds of the range to have consistent datatype - here, that would be intervals. One way to express what you want is:

```
RANGE between interval '1 year' preceding and interval '1 second' preceding
```

Basically this filters out rows up to the preceding second: so this excludes the current row, and no other row, since your expression does not includes seconds anyway.